# select first row after order by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data frame like that:

| date | machine_id | colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24/10/2020 | 001 |  |  |  |
| 13/09/2020 | 001 |  |  |  |
| 14/08/2021 | 097 |  |  |  |
| 12/07/2020 | 097 |  |  |  |
| 25/11/2018 | 231 |  |  |  |
| 16/09/2018 | 231 |  |  |  |

and I get it after a query like that:

SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY machine_id, date DESC

I would like to get online the first row for each machine, that is the most recent date, so this should be the resulting data frame:

| date | machine_id | colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24/10/2020 | 001 |  |  |  |
| 14/08/2021 | 097 |  |  |  |
| 25/11/2018 | 231 |  |  |  |

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try with partitioning the machine_id column and row_number function like the below query

WITH dateframevalues AS (
SELECT val.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY machine_id ORDER BY machine_id DESC) AS rn
FROM yourtable AS val
)
SELECT * FROM dateframevalues WHERE rn = 1;